# React Fetch Request, Remove outer type class name

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch

I am passing data into a Fetch request with React. Its currently passing in object type name also (getPaymentRequest). How do I remove the outer type class? See below.

```
export const getPayments = (
  customerId: number,
  getPaymentsRequest: GetPaymentsRequest,
): Promise<PageSortedResponsePayment> => {
  return kfetch(`/billing-payments-ui/api/getPayments/${customerId}`, {
    method: 'put',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      getPaymentsRequest,
    }),
  });
};

export type GetPaymentsRequest = {
  pageNumber?: number;
  pageSize?: number;
  patientName?: string;
  paymentEndDate?: Date;
  paymentStartDate?: Date;
  paymentStatus?: string;
  sortField?: string;
};
```

**Current:**

```
{"getPaymentsRequest":{"pageNumber":2,"pageSize":10,"paymentEndDate":"2022-09-01T07:00:00.000Z","paymentStartDate":"2020-02-01T08:00:00.000Z"}}
```

**Remove Outer class name:**

```
{"pageNumber":2,"pageSize":10,"paymentEndDate":"2022-09-01T07:00:00.000Z","paymentStartDate":"2020-02-01T08:00:00.000Z"}
```

Comment: maybe you can try this:

body: JSON.stringify({
      ...getPaymentsRequest
    }),

if there is any better solution, please let me know

Comment: hi @SakilKhan feel free to write as answer, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
      ...getPaymentsRequest
    }),
```

if there is any better solution, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Object.keys().

```
const outerClass = Object.keys(getPayments)[0];
const result = getPayments[outerClass];
```

or if your outer always the same just

```
const result = getPayments[getPaymentsRequest];
```